# How to compute k-homology group of 2-sphere?

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology

By M-V sequence we all know that $K_0(S^2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. I wonder the explicit computation. What are the two generators of $K_0(S^2)$? And how do they pair with generators of $K^0(S^2)$, especially with the trivial line bundle and the canonical line bundle?

Comment: This question seems to be quite circular to me: In order to define $K$-homology, you need to use some form of Bott periodicity, which gives you the (co)homology groups of spheres. One way to get geometric representatives of $K$-homology classes on $X$ is as spin_c manifolds $M$ equipped with a vector bundle $E$ and a map $f:M\to X$, representing the pushforward of the Poincare dual of $E$ to $X$ via $f$. The pairing of such a class with $F\in K(X)$ is the index of the Dirac operator twisted by $f^*F\otimes E$. In particular for $S^2$ you can take as the generators the point and $S^2$ itself.